# Tensorflow training killed by system

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am some trouble figuring out why my training is killed by the os during training.

The program can run normally for about 50% of the total training cycles. Then around the last few cycles, the entire program will be killed.

Does tensorflow consume more memory as it trains? Or does it use a constant amount of memory during training?

Note: I am running on a cpu only version of Tensorflow on a virtual machine.

Comment: Can you display the output when the process is being killed? Tensorflow automatically distributes computing resources across all CPUs available unless otherwise specified by `tf.ConfigProto`. Memory used in tensorflow generally remains constant, but this is somewhat dependent on how you read in your data. To check CPU usage during run, in the terminal type `top` and then `1`.

Comment: @user3451457 The terminal just displayed `Killed`. When I used `dmesg` command to check, the last line says something about that being **Out of Memory**, something about killing process or sacrifice child. So on the point on Tensorflow memory usage, So does it mean that once training starts, the memory consumed is more or less constant (Since model is already loaded & I did not read in anymore data once training starts)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that I have included the `tf.global_variables_initializer()` in the training for loop. Once I have remove it from the loop, the memory consumed is stable.

Comment: Will this also occur if I initialize any variable within the loop? I use `global_variables_initializer` outside the loop but i have to initialize 2 variables within the loop and after a few loops, same out of Memory error.

Comment: @Siladittya how are you initializing ur variables?

Comment: I am using STL-10 dataset. First I read the binary files as (5000,96,96,3) numpy array and then convert it to a tensor, then I crete a dataset from that tensor using  `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices`. Then for iteration of Training step, I take a batch of size 40 from the dataset by using `tf.contrib.data.batch_and_drop_remainder(batch_size)`. But to feed the training images using `feed_dict` I have to convert the tensor again to NumPy arrays using `eval()`. But before doing `eval` I convert the tensor to a `tf.Variable` so that the graph doesn't get executed again everytime I call `eval`

Comment: `next_batch = iterator.get_next() ` 
`ni = tf.Variable(next_batch['images'],'bimages')`
`nl = tf.Variable(next_batch['labels'],'blabels')` 
 `sess.run(tf.variables_initializer([ni,nl])) `  

  
This piece of code runs in each loop, where `ni` is of size (40,96,96,3) and dtype = tf.float32

Comment: @Siladittya hi, sorry for taking so long to reply. I am not very sure, but i think it might have something to do with ur tf.variables_initializer().

Comment: So, the step that I am using to initialize the variables in each iteration should be replaced, right? I guess instead of making tensor dataset from numpy array and again converting then to numpy array is a foolish thing. Instead I should keep it as numpy array and feed it directly to `feed_dict`. That is okay?? In that case, the variables storing the image batch, is going to occupy the same amount of space, over all the iterations, i.e. for only 40 images since I use batch size of 40

Comment: @Siladittya i think so.

Comment: In my case, every time a `tf.Variable` is initialized, is it taking up space for that variable and is it not getting cleared?

Comment: But the problem is if I use numpy array I will not get the same functions as I have using te dataset object in tensorflow, I guess. Shuffling and drawing random images from the numpy array, may cause the same image to be drawn many times. So I guess, clearing the variable will be a better option

Comment: @Siladittya actually I am too sure about this. I think python has its own gc? But i found the solution by seeing the offical docs and realised that they only intialize it outside the loop. Once i follow that, the memory issues seems to go away.  I am not too sure for your case.

Comment: @Siladittya but is there a way to maybe convert ur numpy array into the type u wanted during the loop instead of intializing new variables?

Comment: @Siladittya maybe. Not too sure